# When I run the executable after building Unity, the changed scripts are not applied to the build

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

I am making a program with Unity. There has been no problem so far, but suddenly when Unity builds, the changed script is not applied to the executable file.

Changes are applied in the game view, but not only in the built file.

What I've tried is

-Erase existing build files and build again.
-Clone the project, run it in the editor and build

What is the reason and I don't know what to do.

Anyone who has had a similar experience to me, please give me a solution how I solved this problem.